# SQL REPLICATION ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

I have this error and i don't understand what i have to do.
I have tried all day but it doesn't work...

Error messages:
The schema script 'BOOKING_2.sch' could not be propagated to the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)
Get help: ...

The process could not read file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER2012\MSSQL\repldata\unc\K-DEV$MSSQLSERVER2012_FSC_FLIPBOARD_FSC_FLIPBOARD\20130927184606\BOOKING_2.sch' due to OS error 3. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL0)
Get help: ....

Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
 (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL3)
Get help: ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a shared path and not a local path to use as your "remote" publisher. Share a folder on the local server then point the replication to `\\server\shareyouhave`.

Reference: [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/91bc83d3-9e63-4767-9451-2295bd895d70/sql-server-replication-os-error-3)

Answer (score 0):

Create a network share path. And specify the path for Snapshot while configuring
\serverName\shareFolder

[Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DTJC.jpg).